# (Excel VBA) How to Show AutoComplete Feature of a ComboBox as a DropDown List

Tags: vba, excel

I would like the following code to add values to a combobox, then when the user inputs characters into the combobox, the dropdown feature of the combobox will show only those items which contain those characters, similarly to the way the Google Search Bar works.

[image: Google Search Bar]
<sub>(source: [intersites.com](http://intersites.com/resources/uploads/suite_131/google_bar.png))</sub>

Code Edit:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public LC As Long
Public Count As Integer
Dim ComboArray() As String

'Initializes the userform, and saves values from database into an array
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ReDim ComboArray(1 To LC)

For Count = 1 To LC
    ComboArray(Count) = Cells(1, Count).Value
Next Count
End Sub

'Prevents changes if the down key is pressed?
Private Sub ComboBox_SiteName_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

'Adds values to combobox if they contain the string input by user
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim pos As Integer
Dim i As Integer

ComboBox1.Clear

For Count = 1 To LC
    pos = InStr(1, ComboArray(Count), ComboBox1.Value)
    If pos <> 0 Then
        With ComboBox1
            .AddItem Cells(1, Count)
        End With
    End If
Next Count
End Sub
```

Comment: In the code shown, I attempted to first initialize the list items (which works correctly). To create the dropdown effect I am asking for, the code would clear the combobox of all items, and then compare the string within the combobox entry point to each value, adding only those values which contain the string. The code should run every time there is a change in the combobox, specifically entered text.

Comment: Understood, what I'm asking is *what have you tried so far in terms of the desired functionality*? Right now, you've shown zero attempt at solving the problem. You've just shown how to initialize a combobox list values. You know you need to do something on the `_Change` event, so maybe start there? Are you aware of `VBA.Strings` class and the functions associated with that class?

Comment: I have been able to make the combobox show the matching data in the dropdown; however, I would like the dropdown box to automatically be revealed when new text is input.

Comment: Use the `.DropDown` method to display the dropdown list.

Comment: The  `.DropDown` method displays all options, and does not allow me to select any of them. Also, there is a strange scroll bar on the side of the dropdown menu: [image link](https://s31.postimg.org/er4agqssr/Capture.png)

Comment: Right, the `.Dropdown` method displays the current `.List`. You'll need to use some event handlers to filter this list and re-set it during runtime. I have some ideas but I can't get it to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example, which may need refinement for your purposes, but illustrates the general principles of using the `KeyPress` event to build a string of user input, and compare that to each item in the list, effectively filtering the list to values that *start with* the input string.

This needs some refinement to handle backspacing, deleting, etc., which I tried to do, but didn't get as far as I'd like.

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim cbList As Variant
Dim userInput$

'### USERFORM EVENTS
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 8, 48
            'MsgBox "Backspace"
            Debug.Print "Backspace"
            If userInput <> "" Then
            userInput = Left(userInput, Len(userInput) - 1)
            End If
        Case 46
            'MsgBox "Delete"
            Debug.Print "Delete"
            userInput = Replace(userInput, ComboBox1.SelText, "")
    End Select
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim cl As Range
    userInput = ""
    For Each cl In Range("A1:A8")
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem cl.Value
    Next
    Me.ComboBox1.MatchRequired = False
    cbList = Me.ComboBox1.List
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    userInput = ""
End Sub
'#### END USERFORM EVENTS
'#### COMBOBOX EVENTS

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Me.ComboBox1.List = cbList
    ' Capture the user input in module variable
    userInput = userInput & Chr(KeyAscii)
    Debug.Print "input: " & userInput
    Debug.Print KeyAscii
    Dim i As Long, itm
    For i = Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        itm = Me.ComboBox1.List(i)
        If Not StartsWith(CStr(itm), userInput) Then
            Me.ComboBox1.RemoveItem i
        End If
    Next

    If Me.ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
        Me.ComboBox1.List = cbList
    Else
        Me.ComboBox1.List = Me.ComboBox1.List
    End If
    Me.ComboBox1.DropDown

End Sub
'#### END COMBOBOX EVENTS

'#### HELPER FUNCTIONS
Function StartsWith(imtVal$, inputStr$, Optional caseSensitive As Boolean = False)
', Optional caseSensitive As Boolean = False
    'If Not caseSensitive Then
        imtVal = LCase(imtVal)
        inputStr = LCase(inputStr)
    'End If
    StartsWith = VBA.Strings.Left(imtVal, Len(inputStr)) = inputStr
End Function
'#### END HELPER FUNCTIONS
```